# Service 'maas-proxy' failed and unable to locate pacakage lldpd during commissioning

Tags: maas

I am stuck at MAAS 2.6 Commissioning and it fails due to `lldpd` install dependency.
The process fails at the commissioning phase where the new identified machine will change its state from New to Ready

Is this a proxy issue? I am not using any proxy.

I am on a private network and using mobile phone as internet network sharing One windows server connected to MAAS server and all baremetal servers through internet connection sharing I tried no proxy and MAAS-in build proxy in setting tab on MAAS UI.

```
2019-10-14T16:43:19.515867+09:00 ubuntu maas.service_monitor: [error] Service 'proxy' failed to start: Job for maas-proxy.service failed because the control process exited with error code.#012See "systemctl status maas-proxy.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
2019-10-14T16:43:19.594853+09:00 ubuntu maas.service_monitor: [info] Service 'maas-proxy' is not on, it will be started.
2019-10-14T16:43:19.618172+09:00 ubuntu maas.service_monitor: [error] Service 'proxy' failed to start: Job for maas-proxy.service failed because the control process exited with error code.#012See "systemctl status maas-proxy.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

```
2018-11-28 12:42:29 maasserver.region_controller: [critical] Failed configuring proxy.
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 500, in errback
            self._startRunCallbacks(fail)
          File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 567, in _startRunCallbacks
            self._runCallbacks()
          File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 653, in _runCallbacks
            current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
          File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1442, in gotResult
            _inlineCallbacks(r, g, deferred)
        --- <exception caught here> ---
          File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1384, in _inlineCallbacks
            result = result.throwExceptionIntoGenerator(g)
          File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/twisted/python/failure.py", line 408, in throwExceptionIntoGenerator
            return g.throw(self.type, self.value, self.tb)
```

Comment: I am stuck at MAAS 2.6 Commissioning fails due to lldpd install dependency, is this a proxy issue ? , I am not using any proxy , its a private network and using mobile phone as internet network sharing One windows server connected to MAAS server and all baremetal servers through internet connection sharing I tried no proxy and MAAS-in build proxy in setting tab on MAAS UI guys help required

Comment: You can edit your one post via the edit-button. Add some more information: where did you configure the proxy, which part of the installation fails. Is lldpd the only missing package?

Comment: @SimonSudler,  As I mentioned , I haven't configured any proxy and the process fails at the commissioning phase where the new identified machine will change its state from New to Ready . After the ready state , I can proceed with the OS installation . Yes , as the event msg says , its looks like lldpd missing , please refer (Reading package lists...Building dependency tree...Reading state information...E: Unable to locate package lldpd) . One Question I have , is proxy or internet is required in commissioning and installation phase ?

Comment: @SimonSudler , following are the scripts that failed and seen in event log                    (1) 00-maas-03-install-lldpd  (2) 99-maas-02-capture-lldp

Comment: please add this details to your post! Can you also add, from which log file the error messages are coming from?